# Alternate or better approach to aggregateByKey in pyspark RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a weather data csv file in which each entry has station ID and the minimum or max value recorded for that day. The second element is key word to know what the value represents. Sample input is as below.

```
  stationID    feature value
  ITE00100554    TMAX  -75  
  ITE00100554    TMIN -148         
  GM000010962    PRCP    0         
  EZE00100082    TMAX  -86         
  EZE00100082    TMIN -135         
  ITE00100554    TMAX  -60         
  ITE00100554    TMIN -125         
  GM000010962    PRCP    0         
  EZE00100082    TMAX  -44         
  EZE00100082    TMIN -130         
  ITE00100554    TMAX  -23
```

I have filtered out entries with TMIN or TMAX. Each entry is recorded for a given data. I have stripped Date while building my RDD as it's not of interest. My goal is to find the Min and Max value of each station amongst all of its records i.e.,

```
ITE00100554, 'TMIN', <global_min_value recorded by that station>
ITE00100554, 'TMAX', <global_max_value>
EZE00100082, 'TMIN', <global_min_value>
EZE00100082, 'TMAX', <global_max_value>
```

I was able to accomplish this using aggregateByKey, but according to this link https://backtobazics.com/big-data/spark/apache-spark-aggregatebykey-example/ I dont have to use aggregateByKey since the input and output values format is the same. So I would like to know if there are an alternate or better ways to code this without defining so many functions.

```
stationtemps = entries.filter(lambda x: x[1] in ['TMIN', 'TMAX']).map(lambda x: (x[0], (x[1], x[2])))  # (stationID, (tempkey, value))

max_temp = stationtemps.values().values().max()
min_temp = stationtemps.values().values().min()


def max_seqOp(accumulator, element):
    return (accumulator if accumulator[1] > element[1] else element)


def max_combOp(accu1, accu2):
    return (accu1 if accu1[1] > accu2[1] else accu2)


def min_seqOp(accumulator, element):
    return (accumulator if accumulator[1] < element[1] else element)


def min_combOp(accu1, accu2):
    return (accu1 if accu1[1] < accu2[1] else accu2)


station_max_temps = stationtemps.aggregateByKey(('', min_temp), max_seqOp, max_combOp).sortByKey()
station_min_temps = stationtemps.aggregateByKey(('', max_temp), min_seqOp, min_combOp).sortByKey()

min_max_temps = station_max_temps.zip(station_min_temps).collect()

with open('1800_min_max.csv', 'w') as fd:
    writer = csv.writer(fd)
    writer.writerows(map(lambda x: list(list(x)), min_max_temps))
```

I am learning pyspark and havent mastered all different transforming functions.

Comment: Added a second solution.

Comment: What version of spark are you using ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here simulated input and if the min and max is filled in correctly, then why the need for the indicator TMIN, TMAX? Indeed no need for an accumulator.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([  ('s1','tmin',-3), ('s1','tmax', 5), ('s2','tmin',0), ('s2','tmax', 7), ('s0','tmax',14), ('s0','tmin', 3)  ])
rddcollect = rdd.collect()
#print(rddcollect)

rdd2 = rdd.map(lambda x:  (x[0], x[2]))
#rdd2collect = rdd2.collect()
#print(rdd2collect)

rdd3 = rdd2.groupByKey().sortByKey()
rdd4 = rdd3.map(lambda k_v: ( k_v[0], (sorted(k_v[1])))  )
rdd4.collect()
```

returns:

```
Out[27]: [('s0', [3, 14]), ('s1', [-3, 5]), ('s2', [0, 7])]
```

ALTERNATE ANSWER

- after clarification
- assuming that min and max values make sense
- with my own data
- there are other solutions BTW

Here goes:

```
include = ['tmin','tmax']

rdd0 = sc.parallelize([  ('s1','tmin',-3), ('s1','tmax', 5), ('s2','tmin',0), ('s2','tmin',-12), ('s2','tmax', 7), ('s2','tmax', 17), ('s2','tother', 17), ('s0','tmax',14), ('s0','tmin', 3)  ])
rdd1 = rdd0.filter(lambda x: any(e in x for e in include) )
rdd2 = rdd1.map(lambda x:  ( (x[0],x[1]), x[2]))
rdd3 = rdd2.groupByKey().sortByKey()
rdd4Min = rdd3.filter(lambda k_v: k_v[0][1] == 'tmin').map(lambda k_v: ( k_v[0][0], min( k_v[1]  ) ))
rdd4Max = rdd3.filter(lambda k_v: k_v[0][1] == 'tmax').map(lambda k_v: ( k_v[0][0], max( k_v[1]  ) ))
rdd5=rdd4Min.union(rdd4Max)
rdd6 = rdd5.groupByKey().sortByKey()
res = rdd6.map(lambda k_v: ( k_v[0], (sorted(k_v[1]))))
rescollect = res.collect()
print(rescollect)
```

returns:

```
[('s0', [3, 14]), ('s1', [-3, 5]), ('s2', [-12, 17])]
```

Comment: Each entry will have one value, the TMIN and TMAX are to represent what that value means. And you can have more than 2 entries for a station. So if we have 5 stations, it records each station daily TMIN and TMAX for say 30 days. So total entries in the file would be 150 out of which I want to find MiN & max for each station out of the 30 days.

Comment: But you question is very unclear. Why not provide expected output and some input. You state a day. You should be able to work it out from the example of course. Min and Max is of course a little verbose, the values will tell you that.

Comment: How can you have more than 2 entries with classification MIN, MAX?

Comment: I have edited the question with some sample input and expected output format.

Comment: OK, so how two ITE00100554 with TMAX?

Comment: I will post an updated answer to your real question in the weekend.

Comment: @Srinivas  Thanks. Same to you.

Comment: @thebluephantom thanks mate. I've also used the groupByKey() function with the same logic before viewing your answer and got a much simpler code than with aggregateByKey .

Answer (score 1):

Following the same logic as @thebluephantom, this was my final code while reading from csv

```
def get_temp_points(item):
    if item[0][1] == 'TMIN':
        return (item[0], min(item[1]))
    else:
        return (item[0], max(item[1]))


data = lines.filter(lambda x: any(ele for ele in x if ele in ['TMIN', 'TMAX']))

temps = data.map(lambda x: ((x[0], x[2]), float(x[3]))
temp_list = temps.groupByKey().mapValues(list) 
##((stationID, 'TMIN'/'TMAX'), listofvalues)

min_max_temps = temp_list.map(get_temp_points).collect()
```

Comment: That was my other answer actually but I did not get around to it.